# Can't access sub-object in Vue JS 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm pretty new in VueJS and am stuck on the following problem:

I have a template in which a click on a button loads a new template through `router.push` and also sends an ID as data along.

The template:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ content.description }} // Works fine
        {{ content.subobject.logo }} // Logo not found
    </div>
</template>
```

In the new template that is being loaded I have the following function for saving the received ID into data:

```
    created: function() {
        this.ID = this.$route.params.data.toString()
    },
```

then I have a function in methods which uses this ID to get data via `axios/get`:

```
    methods: {
        getContent: function() {
            axios.get("https://api-url.com/" + this.ID)
            .then((response) => {
                this.content = response.data.data
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("ERRR:: ", error.response.data)
            });            
        }

    },
```

this function is called in mounted:

```
    mounted: function() {
        this.getContent()
    }
```

My data function:

```
    data: function() {
    return {
       ID: '',
       content: [] as any
    }
```

The data that is being returned by the API looks something like this:

```
title: "this is the title"
description: "Lorem Ipsum"
subobject: {
   logo: "Logo URL"
}
```

When i use `{{ content.title }}` or `{{ content.description }}` in my template it shows up fine. As soon as I use {{ content.subobject.logo }} I'll get an error "logo" not found.

The funny thing is, when I have the template opend up and add the `{{ content.subobject.logo }}` after the page has loaded, save it, and it hot-reloads, it shows up fine?!

It seems like the data is not "available" on first load - but how can that be, if `{{ content.title }}` works fine?

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: please share the template where your render that logo

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim there isn't anything special. for testing its only <template> <div>{{ content.subobject.logo }}</div></template>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is initially not available which means that `content` is still without inner field values, in order to avoid that add a conditional rendering like :

```
<div v-if="content.subobject">{{ content.subobject.logo }}</div>
```

you could also do :

```
  data: function() {
    return {
       ID: '',
       content: null
    }
}
```

```
<template>
    <template v-if="content">
            <div >{{ content.subobject.logo }}</div>
            <div >{{ content.title }}</div>
    </template>

</template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now it works!! General question: isn't it better to wrap every element around a "v-if" then, just to be sure that it has already loaded?

Comment: @sparks since you're new in Vue world try to focus on Vue 2 then you will be familiar with it you could learn the new concepts introduces in the vue 3